# R programming language symbol

Tags: symbols

I am currently writing a paper where I mention the R programming language. I've seen some papers use a special symbol for R, but I can't figure out how to get it. Here's [an example](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v37/i08/paper).

How do I get that symbol?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is just `\textsf{R}`, or even `\textbf{\textsf{R}}`

Comment: Thanks that works! I am getting a font warning when I use this in a section title although the symbol is properly rendered, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Presumably because you configure your titles in such a way that the combination does not make sense. In most cases these font warnings can be ignored. For instance, there is most likely no sans serif small caps.

Comment: Thanks! [An old thread on R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-February/125688.html) said it should be a standard serif font (i.e., `\newcommand{\R}{R}`), but `\textsf{R}` is what I'm used to seeing. I don't think I have seen `\textbf{\textsf{R}}` anywhere, though.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the R logo from [here](https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png) and then include the following line in your preamble:

```
\newcommand{\Rlogo}{\protect\includegraphics[height=1.8ex,keepaspectratio]{Rlogo.png}}
```

Then you can just write wherever you want:

```
\Rlogo
```

And the result should look like the following:

[image]

For additional info: [here](http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/members/lobry/tmp/tex.pdf).

Good luck!

Comment: Nice try! ;) however you specify a fixed `height`, but the font size may change

Comment: Yes, it's not an ellegant way to do it but in most cases - at least in academic journals - this way you can solve it just fine. Besides, you can easily include the official link to R: href{https://www.r-project.org/}{\Rlogo}

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use the `fontsawesome5` package with \faRProject.

A minimal example should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\faRProject

\end{document}
```

[This link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438206/how-to-transition-best-from-fontawesome-4-to-fontawesome5-in-an-article) should be also interesting to revise if [fontawesome5](https://github.com/xdanaux/fontawesome-latex) package is not available

Comment: To make this answer more acceptable, please provide an example showing the output.  The command you cite isn't shown in the documentation posted on CTAN.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The `\faRProject` command is documented page 30 of `fontsawesome5.pdf`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Barbara mentions in chat (she's having some system errors on the site) that she looked in the wrong fontawesome manual (without the 5), but it is still best to include an image to the answer