# How to transition best from fontawesome (4) to fontawesome5 in an article

Tags: fonts, packages, installing, fontawesome, installing-fonts

I have an old article in which I use fontawesome icons from version 4.7.

In Ubuntu 16.04, I had installed font-awesome (v4.5) and texlive-fonts-extra from the repositories. Then I downloaded the fontawesome 4.7 font from the fontawesome website, and placed the new FontAwesome.otf file at /usr/share/fonts/opentype/font-awesome

This allowed me to use icons in newer releases of fontawesome.

Now fontawesome5 has come up and everything is different, and I do not seem to be able to make it work.

So what would be the best practice to have fontawesome5 up and running?

Please assume I have no idea, walk me through how to install the fontawesome5 package and the fonts.

This is my old MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
%1 - Install font-awesome and texlive-fonts-extra from the repositories
%2 - If you want to use the latest, download font awesome latest version from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/
%3 - Uncompress and copy the FontAwesome.otf file to the following location, replacing current file
%sudo cp FontAwesome.otf /usr/share/fonts/opentype/font-awesome/FontAwesome.otf
%4 - Call symbols newer than your previous version separately
\newcommand\faUserCircle{{\FA\symbol{"F2BD}}}
\newcommand\faIdCard{{\FA\symbol{"F2C2}}}

\begin{document}
some symbols:\\
\faEnvelope\\
\faSkype\\


new symbols:\\
\faUserCircle\\
\faIdCard\\

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: image1]

I want to reproduce it with fontawesome5, including some icon that is new to that release.

I tried the following, but it gives me multiple errors, so I guess I did not install the package or fonts correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
some symbols:\\
\faEnvelope\\
\faSkype\\


new symbols:\\
\faUserCircle\\
\faIdCard\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: What errors would that be?

Comment: "If  you  use  XeLeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX,  you  can  also  directly
download the new Desktop Fonts from
https://fontawesome.com
into your TeX tree.
If you save them with the filenames
FontAwesome5Brands-Regular-400.otf
FontAwesome5Free-Regular-400.otf
FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf
you can start using the new files right away."

Comment: Yes I use lualatex, but where do I store the otf files, how do I install the fontawesome5 package, how do I call the icons, etc? The errors are related to not being able to find the sty files or the icons...

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 comes with TeXLive 2015 while `fontawesome5` is not supported before TeXLive 2017. Even if you manually install the package, it probably fails because `expl3` and LuaTeX are too old. Instead I recommmend installing a "vanilla" TeXLive to get current packages, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu on how to do this.

With TeXLive 2018, `fontawesome5` is available by default and your second example just works.

Comment: OK let me try this

Comment: I have followed the steps to get the newest texlive in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu
It still complains with error `File fontawesome5.sty not found`... Is my system still making use of the old texlive installation (the one I installed from the repositories)?

Answer (score 1):

No problem with up-to-date TL2018 and your example. I downloaded the fonts and *did not* changed the original file names. With LuaLaTeX:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
YJJRQL+LMRoman10-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
IXHJTI+FontAwesome5FreeSolid         CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
QQOXUN+FontAwesome5BrandsRegular     CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      6  0
```

I installed TeXLive on Ubuntu with the following steps:

- first remove the complete Ubuntu/Debian TeXLive installation with 
   `sudo apt remove texlive-full` If it will delete also an TeX editor, then say yes.
- Create the `texlive` directory with `sudo mkdir /usr/local/texlive`
- Set the permission for `texlive` to the user and *not* root (makes
  installtion/updates easier) with `sudo chown <USER> /usr/local/texlive`
  Replace `<USER>` with your username
- Now run `wget https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu/raw/master/install-tl-ubuntu && chmod u+x ./install-tl-ubuntu`
- As an alternative get first the install script with `wget https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu/raw/master/install-tl-ubuntu` and change the permission with `chmod u+x ./install-tl-ubuntu`
- Now we can run the install script as a user: `./install-tl-ubuntu`
- in the end you should have an up-to-date TeXLive 2018
- now install your favorite editor as usual.
- that's all

Comment: Have you tested this without downloading the fonts too? As maintainer of `fontawesome5` I would be very surprised if downloading the free fonts without renaming the files would make any difference.

Comment: Yes, always no problem

Comment: OK but where do I place the fonts, how do I install the fontawesome5 package, etc? Could you provide a full answer with an example?

Comment: I have followed the steps to get the newest texlive in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu
It still complains with error `File fontawesome5.sty not found`... Is my system still making use of the old texlive installation (the one I installed from the repositories)?

Comment: @DaniCee: see my edited answer

Comment: Still get the `File fontawesome5.sty not found` error... what am I doing wrong?? I made the 2018 texlive vanilla installation... do I have to download the fontawesome5 package and place the sty file somewhere?? I thought it came with the fresh installation

Comment: try `kpsewhich fontmath.ltx`. It should output something like `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontmath.ltx`. Do you get similiar output?

Comment: it outputs `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontmath.ltx`

Comment: that looks like an directory from Ubuntus/Debians installation of TeXLive. Do you have also a `/usr/local/texlive` directory?

Comment: yes, the whole new installation is at `/usr/local/texlive/2018`

Comment: OK so now I made sure I uninstalled everything related to my Ubuntu texlive installation and installed texlive 18 again. The output of `kpsewhich fontmath.ltx` is now `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontmath.ltx`. However, when I try to run my example tex file with lualatex I get the error `Error: Could not start the command: lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex`, along with the same error `File fontawesome5.sty not found`

Comment: Will a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.4 and installing TexLive from the repositories solve the problem? I think I am going to give up and try that route, since I've been wanting to try Ubuntu 18.4 for some time now...

Comment: Removing _all_ TeX-related packages (including an editor) and then reinstall TL from the github Link should solve the problem! Hoewever, the link to your binaries is missing. You could append the path in your local `.bashrc`

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled TexStudio after installing TL 2018, and added the following lines in my .bashrc `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux`, `export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/info` and `export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/man`... still I get the errors `Error: Could not start the command: lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex` and `File fontawesome5.sty not found.`

Comment: did you opened a _new_ shell so that the PATH setting is active?

Comment: I edited the paths in my bashrc file right after installing TL a few days ago, since then I have rebooted the computer multiple times... the error persists. Can it be related to how TexStudio is calling LuaLatex?

Comment: no, that should be no problem. Open a terminal, go into your TeX example directory and run by hand `lualatex <myfile>`. Then provide the complete log file for download

Comment: OK, it seems like `lualatex test.tex` has worked, it produces the pdf file satisfactorily, but still when running it in TexStudio gives me the same errors, so it might be a problem with TexStudio...

Comment: Delete TeXstudio with the configuration file and reinstall it. It should then lok for a tex distribution when started at the first time and then sets the path for the programs correct.

Comment: what configuration file?

Comment: ~/.config/texstudio

Comment: That is a directory, should I delete it all?

Comment: yes, and then reinstall texstudio

Comment: Nothing, now TexStudio gives me this `No LaTeX distribution was found on your system. As a result, the corresponding commands are not configured. This means, that you cannot compile your documents to the desired output format (e.g. pdf).

If you intend to work with LaTeX, you'll most certainly want to install a LaTeX distribution.`

Comment: That is curious ... However, go into TeXstudios's  configuration for commands and set the path for e.g. lualatex and the pdf viewer. Then try to run the example from within TeXStudio.

Comment: So at the end I installed Ubuntu 18.04 (with much trouble) almost only for this, but it still does not have the latest version of fontawesome (though it works perfect with fontawesome5 and the MWE above). I confirm I downloaded the latest Desktop version of fontawesome5 and placed the otf files in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome5`, I did have to change the file names to remove the spaces, then run `sudo texhash`, and it worked!